# Modify images as an assembly-line?

Tags: software-recommendation, automation, batch-processing, crop, image-editing

I have many different sizes pictures (scanned) and I would like to crop them at the same size but not at the same coordinates (then I cannot do with XnView automatically).

Do you know a software I could use in order to quickly crop picture after picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a batch action in Photoshop.

1. Open up your first image in Photoshop and create a new action.
2. Crop the image at your desired size.
3. Flatten the image (I believe this is needed to stop Photoshop trying to save as a PSD, since anything with layers is assumed to be saved as a PSD. I havn't tested this extensively with a batch process so it may not be the case but assuming you're saving as an output raster format it isn't going to hurt.)
4. Stop recording your action.
5. Enable the "Show Dialog" option on the "Crop" command in your action in the Actions panel. This will pause the action *before* the crop is applied every time you run the action—allowing you to reposition. It will however remember the size and any other settings.

[image]

You can then create a batch process with your action by going to *File → Automate → Batch...* Simply choose your crop action under the "Play" section, Your folder of images under "Source" and an output under "Destination" (you can either choose a new folder or "Save and Close", which will overwrite the originals).

Your batch process will then pause on every crop so all you need to do is reposition and hit the enter key to continue. Repeat until finished.

[image: Batch Dialog]

You can read more about actions and batch processing in Photoshop here:

- [**Photoshop Help — Creating actions**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html)
- [**Photoshop Help — Process a batch of files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)

Comment: Perfect, just small question before starting, can I export 2 pictures from one picture ? (if it 2-page scan, I need to export the two pages)

Comment: I would like to crop many times the same picture (only two per picture). Maybe a shortcut to come back to the previous picture.

Comment: You can record an undo and save with an action so you could record your action with something like "Crop → Save As → Undo → Crop → Save As". The undo may not even be necessary if you have "Delete Cropped Pixels" unchecked since you can just reposition the crop. If you do have a save as part of the action you can set the "Destination" of the batch to "None" since your action is already doing the save.

Comment: Alternatively you could just run the batch process on the originals twice, making sure you're outputting to a new folder (not overwriting the originals), which may be simpler.

Comment: Yes I did by copying twice pictures :/ the fastest way I found... I will try your idea with Undo. If I run the batch many times, the page numbers won't be right anymore. Anyway, Thank you very much !